Loss in KE in terms of reduced mass and coefficient of restitution
(This is very similar to this question - except I have derived the equation and am now looking for a simpler way.)
The Equation
The change in the systems overall KE after a collision between two smooth particles, A and B, is given by $$\Delta K = \frac12 \mu \left(\vec{U} \cdot \hat{i}\right)^2\left(e^2 - 1\right)$$
Where:

$\mu = \frac{m_A m_B}{m_A + m_B}$, the system's reduced mass
$e=- \frac{\vec{V} \cdot \hat{i}}{\vec{U} \cdot \hat{i}}$, the coefficient of restitution between the particles
$\vec{U} = \vec{u_A} - \vec{u_B}$ and $\vec{V} = \vec{v_A} - \vec{v_B}$ are the relative velocities of approach and separation of the particles (as seen from the frame of reference of B - we could alternatively define them from A's frame of reference - it wouldn't matter)
$\hat{i}$ is a unit vector parallel with the impulse experienced by the particles

Note that the original equation on Wikipedia used $v_{rel}$ (instead of $\vec{U} \cdot \hat{i}$) which it described as "the relative velocity of the bodies before collision." I have had to assume that it intended to mean "the component of the relative velocity of the bodies before collision that is parallel to the imuplse they experience".
My Derivation Attempt
$$\Delta K = \frac12 m_A v_A^2 + \frac12 m_B v_B^2 - \frac12 m_A u_A^2 - \frac12 m_B u_B^2 \implies 2 \Delta K = m_A \left( v_A^2 - u_A^2 \right) + m_B \left( v_B^2 - u_B^2 \right) \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Notice that in the directions of $\hat{j}$ and $\hat{k}$, there is no component of the impulse the particles experienced, so the components of their velocities in these directions are unchanged after the collision. (I.e. $\vec{u_A} \cdot \hat{j} = \vec{v_A} \cdot \hat{j}$ and $\vec{u_A} \cdot \hat{k} = \vec{v_A} \cdot \hat{k}$, and the same for B.)
$\therefore v_A^2 - u_A^2 = (v_{Ax})^2 - (u_{Ax})^2$ (where, concisely, $v_{Ax} = \vec{v_A} \cdot \hat{i}$) and similarly for B.
This allows us to rewrite $\eqref{1}$. We can also use the 'difference of two squares'.
$$2 \Delta K = m_A \left( v_{Ax}^2 - u_{Ax}^2 \right) + m_B \left( v_{Bx}^2 - u_{Bx}^2 \right) = m_A \left( v_{Ax} - u_{Ax} \right) \left( v_{Ax} + u_{Ax} \right) + m_B \left( v_{Bx} - u_{Bx} \right) \left( v_{Bx} + u_{Bx} \right) \tag{2}\label{2}$$
Note, by Newton's 3rd Law, or conservation of momentum, the impulses experienced by A and B will be equal in magnitude and opposite in direction.
$$\therefore m_A\left(\vec{v_A}-\vec{u_A}\right) = -m_B\left(\vec{v_B}-\vec{u_B}\right)$$
Taking the dot product of both sides of this equation with $\hat{i}$ (i.e. conserving momentum along the direction of the impulse) gives: $m_A \left( v_{Ax} - u_{Ax} \right) = - m_B \left( v_{Bx} - u_{Bx} \right)$, which I will call $I$ for simplicity.
Re-writing $\eqref{2}$: $$2 \Delta K = I \left( v_{Ax} + u_{Ax} \right) - I \left( v_{Bx} + u_{Bx} \right) = I \left( v_{Ax} - v_{Bx} + u_{Ax} - u_{Bx}\right) \tag{3}\label{3}$$
From the definition of the coefficient of restitution: $$ e= - \frac{\left(\vec{v_A}-\vec{v_B}\right) \cdot \hat{i}}{\left(\vec{u_A}-\vec{u_B}\right) \cdot \hat{i}} \implies v_{Ax} - v_{Bx}= -e \left(u_{Ax} - u_{Bx}\right)$$
So from $\eqref{3}$:$$2 \Delta K = I \left[ -e \left(u_{Ax} - u_{Bx}\right)  + u_{Ax} - u_{Bx}\right] = I \left(u_{Ax} - u_{Bx}\right) (1-e) \tag{4}\label{4}$$
Again, it follows from the definition of the coefficient of restitution that $$e = \frac{-(v_{Ax} - v_{Bx})}{u_{Ax}-u_{Bx}} \implies e+1 = \frac{-(v_{Ax} - v_{Bx}) + (u_{Ax}-u_{Bx})}{u_{Ax}-u_{Bx}} $$
$$\therefore (e+1)(u_{Ax} - u_{Bx}) = - (v_{Ax} - u_{Ax}) + v_{Bx} - u_{Bx} \tag{5}\label{5}$$
Recalling our definition of $I$ (the impulse on A),
$$m_A \left( v_{Ax} - u_{Ax} \right) = - m_B \left( v_{Bx} - u_{Bx} \right) = I$$
$$\implies v_{Ax} - u_{Ax} = \frac{I}{m_A}; v_{Bx} - u_{Bx} = -\frac{I}{m_B}$$
Substituting these results into $/eqref{5}$, and noticing that $\frac{1}{\mu} = \frac{m_A +m_B}{m_A m_B} = \frac{1}{m_A} + \frac{1}{m_B}$, from our definition of reduced mass:
$$(e+1)(u_{Ax} - u_{Bx}) = - \frac{I}{m_A} - \frac{I}{m_B} = - \frac{I}{\mu}$$
$$ \implies I = - \mu (u_{Ax}-u_{Bx})(1+e)$$
Substituting the above expression for $I$ into $\eqref{4}$, we get:
$$2 \Delta K = -\mu (u_{Ax}-u_{Bx})^2 (1-e^2)$$
Finally, notice that $\vec{U} \cdot \hat{i} = (\vec{u_A} - \vec{u_B}) \cdot \hat{i} = u_{Ax} - u_{Bx}$.
$$ \therefore \Delta K = \frac12 \mu \left(\vec{U} \cdot \hat{i}\right)^2\left(e^2 - 1\right)$$
(Sidenote: I guess the nice thing about this equation is that it also shows you that the change in KE is the same, regardless of whichever inertial reference frame you view the situation with, because $\vec{U}$ will be the same in all relativley inertial frames.)
My Question
Does anyone have a nicer, shorter derivation, in a sequence that is more logical (as in it would be more natural and obvious to go from one step to the next)? Because I really had to play around for a while until I eventually got $I = - \mu (u_{Ax}-u_{Bx})(1+e)$.

You have a square too many in your last (and first) equation.

Ah thank you - spotted it now

This is quite straightforward to solve in the center of mass reference frame. Here we have
$\vec{u_A} =\frac{m_B}{m_A+m_B} \vec{u}$
$\vec{u_B} =-\frac{m_A}{m_A+m_B} \vec{u}$
where $\vec{u} = \vec{u_A}-\vec{u_B}$
So the initial kinetic energies are
$K_A = \frac{m_A}{2}\cdot \vec{u_A}^2 = \frac{m_A}{2}\frac{m_B^2}{(m_A+m_B)^2} \vec{u}^2 = \frac {m_B}{m_A+m_B} \frac{\mu}{2}\vec u^2 $
$K_B = \frac{m_B}{2}\cdot \vec{u_B}^2 = \frac{m_B}{2}\frac{m_A^2}{(m_A+m_B)^2} \vec{u}^2 = \frac {m_A}{m_A+m_B} \frac{\mu}{2}\vec u^2 $
where
$\mu = \frac {m_A m_B}{m_A+m_B}$
and the total energy is thus
$K=K_A+K_B = \frac{\mu}{2} u^2 $
After collision the relative speed $u$ is changed changed to $e\cdot u$, so the total kinetic energy is then
$K'= \frac{\mu}{2} e^2 u^2 $
which means the energy loss is
$\Delta K = K'-K =  \frac{\mu}{2} u^2 \cdot (e^2-1) $
